# Can rvest keep inline html tags such as <br> using html_table?

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table in R that I have been given in html form. Rvest was super useful in getting all of the text out of the table, but I would like to keep the inline styling that occurs in its HTML form.

For example, text in the table might be

```
"This is a sentence <BR> this is another sentence"
```

I would like to preserve the BR

I've tried reading in the whole table:

```
my_table <- my_table_html %>% 
html_nodes("table") %>% 
html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

I've also tried selecting specific columns in the table:

```
my_column <- my_table_html %>% 
html_nodes(".Tabletitle:nth-child(2)") %>%
html_text()
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm hoping to do the same thing with html_text().

Comment: There's a solution in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18661076/635806 -- perhaps it can be adapted to rvest / xml2.

Answer (score 15):

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

pg <- read_html("This is a sentence <BR> this is another sentence")

xml_find_all(pg, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", "\n")

xml_find_all(pg, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()

html_text(pg)
## [1] "This is a sentence \n this is another sentence"
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what this does? I'm trying to adapt it to my own code and I'm getting the error: `could not find function "xml_add_sibling"`

Comment: That is because `xml_add_sibling()` is from the `xml2` package, which needs to be loaded for this to work. I have edited the post accordingly.