# How to extract specific data from web page to add it to a scraped table with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have already built a script that extracts the data from a table hosted on the web, I can already visualize the tables but to complement it I need to add the provider data as a column of the table that is already built, I would like to know how I can extract the provider data to append to my table

Scrip R

```
library(rvest)

urls.colombia.compra.microsoft <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")


base.colombia.compra.microsft <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.microsoft, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.microsft

urls.colombia.compra.google <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Google&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.google <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.google, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.google

urls.colombia.compra.nube <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                                      0:11, 
                                      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Nube%20Pública%20III&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.nube <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.nube, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.nube

base.consolidada.colombia.compra <- data.table::rbindlist(list(base.colombia.compra.microsft, 
                        base.colombia.compra.google, 
                        base.colombia.compra.nube), idcol = 'id')

base.consolidada.colombia.compra

all_urls <- paste0('https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/', base.consolidada.colombia.compra$`Orden de Compra`)

new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]] %>% dplyr::mutate(order_number = basename(.x), .before = 1))

new_res

library(dplyr)

Base.articulos.colombia.compra <- new_res %>% filter(!is.na(No))
```

The supplier data looks like this:

[image: Provider data image]

Comment: Are you doing to repeat info? You have repeat order_numbers due to different artículos. It would be helpful to shown one example desired final output entry for a given order_number (including all rows against that order_number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to there being repeated `order_number`s, with different `artículos`, with your current structure, adding additional columns for the requested data could mean repeating the same new data across all rows for a given `order_number`. That seems the simplest condition to accept in order to deliver your requirement.

If that is ok, then you can simply add to your `mutate()` call, within the anon func, and add those additional columns. Personally, I chose to add to the `mutate` but replace the anon func with an explicit function as shown below. I then pass that function to `map_df`.

I also swop out grabbing all tables, then indexing, for selecting the single table more efficiently with a class selector returning 1 node.

I finally added a `tidy_node` function, an adaptation of an answer given by [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755666), in which I preserve space between words, where `br` styling was present in the html. The function adds in a `,`  to preserve readability. This requires an additional library reference.

```
library(xml2)

tidy_node <- function(node){
  xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", ", ")
  xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()
  return(node)
}

get_order_details <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>%
    read_html()
  additional_columns <- page %>% html_elements("#supplier .oc-span")
  table <- page %>%
    html_element(".sticky-enabled") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      order_number = basename(url), .before = 1,
      Nombre = additional_columns[1] %>% html_text(),
      `Dirección Principal` = tidy_node(additional_columns[2]) %>% html_text(trim = T),
      `Teléfono (Del Trabajo)` = additional_columns[3] %>% html_text(),
      `Teléfono (Celular)` = additional_columns[4] %>% html_text()
    )
}

new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, get_order_details)
```

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

tidy_node <- function(node){
  xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", ", ")
  xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()
  return(node)
}

get_order_details <- function(url) {
  page <- url %>%
    read_html()
  additional_columns <- page %>% html_elements("#supplier .oc-span")
  table <- page %>%
    html_element(".sticky-enabled") %>%
    html_table() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      order_number = basename(url), .before = 1,
      Nombre = additional_columns[1] %>% html_text(),
      `Dirección Principal` = tidy_node(additional_columns[2]) %>% html_text(trim = T),
      `Teléfono (Del Trabajo)` = additional_columns[3] %>% html_text(),
      `Teléfono (Celular)` = additional_columns[4] %>% html_text()
    )
}


urls.colombia.compra.microsoft <- paste0(
  "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
  0:11,
  "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
)

base.colombia.compra.microsft <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.microsoft, ~ .x %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table())

base.colombia.compra.microsft

urls.colombia.compra.google <- paste0(
  "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
  0:11,
  "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Google&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
)

base.colombia.compra.google <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.google, ~ .x %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table())

base.colombia.compra.google

urls.colombia.compra.nube <- paste0(
  "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
  0:11,
  "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Nube%20Pública%20III&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
)

base.colombia.compra.nube <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.nube, ~ .x %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table())

base.colombia.compra.nube

base.consolidada.colombia.compra <- data.table::rbindlist(list(
  base.colombia.compra.microsft,
  base.colombia.compra.google,
  base.colombia.compra.nube
), idcol = "id")

base.consolidada.colombia.compra

all_urls <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/", base.consolidada.colombia.compra$`Orden de Compra`)

new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, get_order_details)

new_res

Base.articulos.colombia.compra <- new_res %>% filter(!is.na(No))
```

Comment: On  "new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, get_order_details)"  in I must have include "all_urls" of this line "all_urls <- paste0 ('https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/', base.consolidada.colombia. compra $ `Orden de compra`)"?

Comment: How can I build a table with the data containing the purchase orders?

Comment: Hi, I posted just the bits you needed to add/amend. I have now posted those bits inside of your existing code as an edit.

Comment: I can also get the name of the providers?

Comment: You have the name as Nombre column. 2nd column of df.

Comment: How can I remove the $ symbol from money values?

Comment: I don't see any $ in the returned `Precio|Total`

Comment: The total of "base.consolidada.colombia.compra" has $

Comment: I'll have a look this eve. Should be a simple gsub

Comment: `base.consolidada.colombia.compra <- base.consolidada.colombia.compra %>% mutate(Total = gsub('\\$','', Total))`