# Web-scraping using "rvest" package, how do I loop over a bunch of county FIPS codes?

Tags: r, loops, rvest, fips

So I'm trying to acquire farm subsidy data from a website, I've figured out how to scrape what I'm looking for, now I'm trying to loop over all counties in a state (CO) to acquire these subsidy data by year from all counties. I'm okay with either (a) having an individual .csv for each county after the loop runs or (b) having them all compiled into one data frame then saved as a .csv.

Below is an example of the scraping completed for just one county. Now I'd like to write a loop that goes through the fips codes 08003, 08005, 08007, 08009, and 08011 for now (I can extrapolate this to other counties in CO later).

```
# Starting with Adams County
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


link = "https://farm.ewg.org/regionsummary.php?fips=08001"
page = read_html(link)

year = page %>% html_nodes("tr~ tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
year

subs = page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
subs

  subsidy_data <- data.frame(subs)

  subs = data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(subsidy_data$subs), "$", fixed = TRUE)))
  
  sub_data <- cbind(year, subs)
  sub_data <- sub_data[-c(28),]

cons_sub_rec = page %>% html_nodes("td~ td+ td small:nth-child(1) em") %>% html_text()
cons_sub_rec <- cons_sub_rec[-c(28)]

dis_sub_rec = page %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(3) em") %>% html_text()

comm_sub_rec = page %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(5) em") %>% html_text()

ins_sub_rec = page %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(7) em") %>% html_text()

  sub_data <- cbind(year, subs, cons_sub_rec, dis_sub_rec, comm_sub_rec, ins_sub_rec)
  
  sub_data$fips = 8001
  
  write.csv(sub_data,"filepath/ewg_sub_8001.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Any and all suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: It is helpful often to include a couple of rows of desired output to guide people. You can insert these via [edit] using the table tool SO has or by using a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to generate table and then enter in to question, select all table and press Ctrl + K to indent and display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a request to the geo file to first collect all the county codes and names associated with a given state. This can be done with a helper function. You can then write an additional helper function to tidy the html, returned from each request to a given webpage (where the url is constructed from a base string joined with county id/code), into a single DataFrame containing the info of interest. Map that latter function with `future_map_dfr`, from `furrr`, to return a single DataFrame.

Notes:

Code is written with R 4.1.0+ syntax.

Credit to  [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755666) for approach to handling `br` elements.

---

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
library(xml2)

state_county_codes <- \(state_code){
  read_html(sprintf("https://farm.ewg.org/ammap/maps/js/%sCounties.js", state_code)) |>
    html_text() |>
    stringr::str_match("(\\[.*\\])") |>
    {
      \(x) x[, 1]
    }() |>
    jsonlite::parse_json(simplifyVector = T) |>
    select(-d) |>
    mutate(
      id = substr(id, 2, 6),
      webpage = paste0("https://farm.ewg.org/regionsummary.php?fips=", id)
    ) |>
    tibble() -> df
}

county_summary <- \(county_code) {
  page <- read_html(sprintf("https://farm.ewg.org/regionsummary.php?fips=%s", county_code))

  xml_find_all(page, ".//br") |> xml_add_sibling("p", "#")
  xml_find_all(page, ".//br") |> xml_remove()

  t <- page |>
    html_element(".table") |>
    html_table()

  t <- t[-c(5)] |> clean_names()

  df <- data.frame(
    id = county_code,
    year = t$year |> stringi::stri_remove_empty() |> rep(4) |>
      {
        \(x) stringr::str_replace(x, "‡", "")
      }(),
    `subsidy_category` = stringr::str_split_fixed(t$`subsidy_category`, "#", 4) |> stringi::stri_remove_empty() |> as.vector(),
    amount = stringr::str_split_fixed(t$`subsidy_category_2`, "#", 4) |> stringi::stri_remove_empty() |> as.vector(),
    number = stringr::str_split_fixed(t$`subsidy_category_3`, "#", 4) |> stringi::stri_remove_empty() |> as.vector()
  )
}

state_code <- "co"

counties <- state_county_codes(state_code)

no_cores <- future::availableCores() - 1
future::plan(future::multisession, workers = no_cores)
results <- future_map_dfr(counties$id, .f = county_summary)

final <- dplyr::left_join(results, counties, by = "id") |>
  select(title, everything()) |>
  rename(county = title)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Oh awesome, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! One more question for you, how would I adapt this code to include additional states? (Nebraska and Wyoming, for example)

Comment: I would alter `state_county_codes()` to include the state name and state code as columns. I would then use future_map_dfr, applied to list of state codes, to generate 1 big initial df of all state codes. Then proceed as before. Depending on length of id column I would decide it batches of requests would be needed with pauses in between. I would also first want to confirm no duplicate ids. I don't think so but would check before launching the larger second request for the actual final data items.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as shown doesn't work, so I made the quickest corrections that made sense to me in the below.

The idea here is to capture the steps that you want to loop over in a custom function, where the variable going in is whatever you want to loop. Then use `purrr::map()` to map over the fips codes with this function.

```
library(rvest)

fips <- c(08001, 08003, 08005, 08007, 08009,  08011)

get_fips_data <- function(x) {
  url <- paste("https://farm.ewg.org/regionsummary.php?fips=", x)
  site <- read_html(url)
  
  year = site %>% html_nodes("tr~ tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()

  subs = site %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()

  subsidy_data <- data.frame(subs)

  subs = data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(as.character(subsidy_data$subs), "$", fixed = TRUE)))

  sub_data <- cbind(year, subs)
  sub_data <- sub_data[-28,]

  cons_sub_rec = site %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(1) em") %>% html_text()
  cons_sub_rec <- cons_sub_rec[-28]

  dis_sub_rec = site %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(3) em") %>% html_text()

  comm_sub_rec = site %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(5) em") %>% html_text()

  ins_sub_rec = site %>% html_nodes("small:nth-child(7) em") %>% html_text()

  cbind(year, subs, cons_sub_rec, dis_sub_rec, comm_sub_rec, ins_sub_rec)
}


fips %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(get_fips_data, .id = "fips")
```

Comment: I apologize for the code not running correctly, corrected them and they match the page I was using. While I can get your code to run, it seems to produce values quite a bit larger than the ones on the website I'm scraping from. Maybe it has to do with the faulty code I started with?