# Scrape object from html with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new in web scraping with r and I am trying to get a daily updated object which is probably not text. The url is
[here](https://covid19.public.lu/en.html) and I want to extract the daily situation table in the end of the page. The class of this object is

```
class="aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn--default--12 aem-GridColumn--offset--default--0"
```

I am not really experienced with html and css so if you have any useful source or advice on how I can extract objects from a webpage I would really appreciate it, since `SelectorGadget` in that case indicate "No valid path found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the text obtained from `Daily situation update` using `vroom` package

```
library(rvest)
library(vroom)

url = 'https://covid19.public.lu/en.html'
df = url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('.cmp-gridStat__item-container') %>% 
  html_text2()

vroom(df, delim = '\\n', col_names = F)

# A tibble: 22 x 1
   X1                                     
   <chr>                                  
 1 369 People tested positive for COVID-19
 2 Per 100.000 inhabitants: 58,13         
 3 Unvaccinated: 91,20
```

Edit:

**`html_element` vs `html_elemnts`**

The pout of `html_elemnts` (html_nodes) is,

```
[1] "369 People tested positive for COVID-19\n\nPer 100.000 inhabitants: 58,13\n\nUnvaccinated: 91,20\n\nVaccinated: 41,72\n\nRatio Unvaccinated / Vaccinated: 2,19\n\n "
[2] "4 625 Number of PCR tests performed\n\nPer 100.000 inhabitants: 729\n\nPositivity rate in %: 7,98\n\nReproduction rate: 0,97"                                       
[3] "80 Hospitalizations\n\nNormal care: 57\nIntensive care: 23\n\nNew deaths: 1\nTotal deaths: 890"                                                                     
[4] "6 520 Vaccinations per day\n\nDose 1: 785\nDose 2: 468\nComplementary dose: 5 267"                                                                                  
[5] "960 315 Total vaccines administered\n\nDose 1: 452 387\nDose 2: 395 044\nComplementary dose: 112 884"
```

and that of `html_element` (html_node)` is

```
[1] "369 People tested positive for COVID-19\n\nPer 100.000 inhabitants: 58,13\n\nUnvaccinated: 91,20\n\nVaccinated: 41,72\n\nRatio Unvaccinated / Vaccinated: 2,19\n\n "
```

As you can see `html_nodes` returns all value associated with the nodes whereas`html_node` only returns the first node. Thus, the former fetches you all the nodes which is really helpful.

**`html_text` vs `html_text2`**

The `html_text2`retains the breaks in strings usually `\n` and `\b`. These are helpful when working with strings.

More info is in `rvest` documentation,
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf

Comment: Thank you a lot I think I am gonna choose your solution! Could you please tell me what is the difference between the html_nodes and html_node functions and what is the difference between html_text2 and html_text ?

Comment: Check the modified answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without getting into the business of writing web scrapers, I think this should help you out:

```r
library(rvest)
url = 'https://covid19.public.lu/en.html'
source = read_html(url)
selection = html_nodes( source , '.cmp-gridStat__item-container' ) %>% html_node( '.number' ) %>% html_text() %>% toString()
```

Comment: wow that is cool

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer is helpful as a resource too!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a much more elegant way to do this efficiently, but when I need brute force something like this, I try to break it down into small parts.

1. Use the [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) library to get the raw html.
2. Use [str_extract](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_extract.html) from the [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) library to extract the specific piece of data from the html.
3. I use both a [positive lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) regex to get the exact piece of data I need. It basically takes the form of "?<=text_right_before).+?(?=text_right_after)

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)

r <- GET("https://covid19.public.lu/en.html")
html<-content(r, "text")

normal_care=str_extract(html, regex("(?<=Normal care: ).+?(?=<br>)"))
intensive_care=str_extract(html, regex("(?<=Intensive care: ).+?(?=</p>)"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you elaborate a bit on the regex. How I can identify what I need to express from this <p>Normal care: 57<br> Intensive care: 23</p> \n<p> ?

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if you could get the same data from any of their public APIs. If you simply want a pdf with that table (plus lots of other tables of useful info) you can use the API to extract.

If you want as a DataFrame (resembling as per webpage) you can write a user defined function, with the help of `pdftools`, to reconstruct the table from the pdf. Bit more effort but as you already have other answers covering using `rvest` thought I'd have a look at this. I looked at `tabularize` but that wasn't particularly effective.

More than likely, you could pull several of the API datasets together to get the full content without the need to parse the pdf publication I use e.g. there is an Excel spreadsheet that gives the case numbers.

N.B. There are a few bottom calcs from the webpage not included below. I have only processed the testing info table from the pdf.

---

**Rapports journaliers:**

https://data.public.lu/en/datasets/covid-19-rapports-journaliers/#_
https://download.data.public.lu/resources/covid-19-rapports-journaliers/20211210-165252/coronavirus-rapport-journalier-10122021.pdf

**API datasets:**

https://data.public.lu/api/1/datasets/#

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
## https://data.library.virginia.edu/reading-pdf-files-into-r-for-text-mining/
# install.packages("pdftools")
library(pdftools)

r <- jsonlite::read_json("https://data.public.lu/api/1/datasets/#")
report_index <- match(TRUE, map(r$data, function(x) x$slug == "covid-19-rapports-journaliers"))
latest_daily_covid_pdf <- r$data[[report_index]]$resources[[1]]$latest # coronavirus-rapport-journalier

filename <- "covd_daily.pdf"

download.file(latest_daily_covid_pdf, filename, mode = "wb")

get_latest_daily_df <- function(filename) {
  
  data <- pdf_text(filename)

  text <- data[[1]] %>% strsplit(split = "\n{2,}")

  web_data <- text[[1]][3:12]

  df <- map(web_data, function(x) strsplit(x, split = "\\s{2,}")) %>%
    unlist() %>%
    matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 5, byrow = T) %>%
    as_tibble()

  colnames(df) <- text[[1]][2] %>%
    strsplit(split = "\\s{2,}") %>%
    map(function(x) gsub("(.*[a-z])\\d+", "\\1", x)) %>%
    unlist()

  title <- text[[1]][1] %>%
    strsplit(split = "\n") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    tail(1) %>%
    gsub("\\s+", " ", .) %>%
    gsub(" TOTAL", "", .)

  colnames(df)[2:3] <- colnames(df)[2:3] %>% paste(title, ., sep = " ")
  colnames(df)[4:5] <- colnames(df)[4:5] %>% paste("TOTAL", ., sep = " ")
  colnames(df)[1] <- "Metric"

  clean_col <- function(x) {
    gsub("\\s+|,", "", x) %>% as.numeric()
  }

  clean_col2 <- function(x) {
    gsub("\n", " ", gsub("([a-z])(\\d+)", "\\1", x))
  }

  df <- df %>% mutate(across(.cols = -c(colnames(df)[1]), clean_col),
    Metric = clean_col2(Metric)
  )

  return(df)
}


View(get_latest_daily_df(filename))
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Alternate:**

If you simply want to pull items then process you could extract each column as an item in a list. Replace br elements such that the content within those end up in a comma separated list:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
library(xml2)

page <- read_html("https://covid19.public.lu/en.html")
xml_find_all(page, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("span", ",") #This method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755666 @hrbrmstr
xml_find_all(page, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()

columns <- page %>% html_elements(".cmp-gridStat__item")

map(columns, ~ .x %>%
  html_elements("p") %>%
  html_text(trim = T) %>%
  gsub("\n\\s{2,}", " ", .)
  %>%
  stri_remove_empty())
```

Comment: This is a great! I would really appreciate if you have the time to elaborate a bit in the use of map function in both scripts. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `map` simply applies the user defined function to a list. In this case the list is the 5 _"columns"_