# How to handle rowspan and colspan while scraping a Table using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from table (HTML pasted below):

I tried to use below code, but it does not return the contents as required. It merges all names in one for the rows (where rowspan is mentioned). Refer Table1 below.

This table does have structural issues as it is using br tags. Could someone please help me to get a table with values mapped properly to all items. (Like Table 2)

```
<!--HTML for Table -->
<table frame="hsides" rules="groups" class="rendered small default_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Characteristics</th>
      <th align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Values, n (%)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" colspan="1">Sex <br />Male <br />Female </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">75 (74.3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">26 (25.7)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" colspan="1">Age <br />&#x0003c;70 years of age <br />&#x02265;70 years of age </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">63 (62.4) <br />38 (37.6) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" colspan="1">Smoking history <br />Yes <br />No </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">93 (92.1) <br />8 (7.9) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Histology <br />Adenocarcinoma <br />Squamous <br />NSCLC poorly differentiated <br />Others </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />69 (68.3) <br />19 (18.8) <br />9 (8.9) <br />4 (4.0)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Disease stage <br />IIIB <br />IV </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />2 (2.3) <br />86 (97.7)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Brain metastases <br />Yes <br />No </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">16 (15.8) <br />85 (84.2) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">PD-L1 TPS% <br />&#x0003c;90% <br />&#x02265;90% </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />74 (73.3) <br />27 (26.7)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">ECOG PS <br />0 <br />1 <br />2 <br />3 </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />20 (19.8) <br />43 (42.6) <br />30 (29.7) <br />8 (7.9)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">CCI <br />0&#x02013;2 <br />&#x02265;3 </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />91 (90.1) <br />10 (9.9)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">NLR <br />&#x02265;4 <br />&#x0003c;4 </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />58 (57.4) <br />43 (42.6)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Frailty Scoring System <br />Low <br />Intermediate <br />High </td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" style="border-top:solid thin;border-bottom:solid thin" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <br />28 (27.7) <br />41 (40.6) <br />32 (31.7)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




#R Code

library(rvest)
tbls <- html_table(read_html("c:/GenderStats.html"))
for (t in 1:length(tbls)) {
  assign(paste0("Table", t), tbls[[t]])
}


#Table 1

    # A tibble: 15 × 2
            Characteristics                                                         `Values, n (%)`                     
            <chr>                                                                   <chr>                               
     1      SexMaleFemale                                                           ""                                  
     2      SexMaleFemale                                                           "75 (74.3)"                         
     3      SexMaleFemale                                                           "26 (25.7)"                         
     4      Age<70 years of age≥70 years of age                                     ""                                  
     5      Age<70 years of age≥70 years of age                                     "63 (62.4)38 (37.6)"                
     6      Smoking historyYesNo                                                    ""                                  
     7      Smoking historyYesNo                                                    "93 (92.1)8 (7.9)"                  
     8      HistologyAdenocarcinomaSquamousNSCLC poorly differentiatedOthers        "69 (68.3)19 (18.8)9 (8.9)4 (4.0)"  
     9      Disease stageIIIBIV                                                     "2 (2.3)86 (97.7)"                  
    10      Brain metastasesYesNo                                                   "16 (15.8)85 (84.2)"                
    11      PD-L1 TPS%<90%≥90%                                                      "74 (73.3)27 (26.7)"                
    12      ECOG PS0123                                                             "20 (19.8)43 (42.6)30 (29.7)8 (7.9)"
    13      CCI0–2≥3                                                                "91 (90.1)10 (9.9)"                 
    14      NLR≥4<4                                                                 "58 (57.4)43 (42.6)"                
    15      Frailty Scoring SystemLowIntermediateHigh                               "28 (27.7)41 (40.6)32 (31.7)"



**Is there a way to get like below attached table?**

    

#Table 2

    # A tibble: 38 × 2
       Characteristics             `Values, n (%)`
       <chr>                       <chr>          
     1 Sex                         ""             
     2 Male                        "75 (74.3)"    
     3 Female                      "26 (25.7)"    
     4 Age                         ""             
     5 <70 years of age            "63 (62.4)"    
     6 >=70 years of age           "38 (37.6)"    
     7 Smoking history             ""             
     8 Yes                         "93 (92.1)"    
     9 No                          "8 (7.9)"      
    10 Histology                   ""             
    11 Adenocarcinoma              "69 (68.3)"    
    12 Squamous                    "19 (18.8)"    
    13 NSCLC poorly differentiated "9 (8.9)"      
    14 Others                      "4 (4.0)"      
    15 Disease stage               ""             
    16 IIIB                        "2 (2.3)"      
    17 IV                          "86 (97.7)"    
    18 Brain metastases            ""             
    19 Yes                         "16 (15.8)"    
    20 No                          "85 (84.2)"    
    21 PD-L1 TPS%                  ""             
    22 <90%                        "74 (73.3)"    
    23 >=90%                       "27 (26.7)"    
    24 ECOG PS                     ""             
    25 0                           "20 (19.8)"    
    26 1                           "43 (42.6)"    
    27 2                           "30 (29.7)"    
    28 3                           "8 (7.9)"      
    29 CCI                         ""             
    30 0-2                         "91 (90.1)"    
    31 >=3                         "10 (9.9)"     
    32 NLR                         ""             
    33 >=4                         "58 (57.4)"    
    34 <4                          "43 (42.6)"    
    35 Frailty Scoring System      ""             
    36 Low                         "28 (27.7)"    
    37 Intermediate                "41 (40.6)"    
    38 High                        "32 (31.7)"
```

Comment: The problem is that this HTML uses line breaks (<br>) in one column to align labels to values in `<td>` cells in other column.  There's nothing structural that allows for mapping list names to values.  You might be able to create a list of labels, by splitting on <br>, and then map that to the Value <td>s, including the empty first one - but that isn't a very sturdy solution.  The quality of the HTML here will limit scraping options.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  But please post output tables inline, as code, instead of screenshots - screenshots don't show up for screen readers.

Comment: Separately - I get a 403 error when trying to load that URL from `rvest::read_html`.

Comment: I have updated tables inline and also the HTML now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
Based on OP's updated HTML, here's a way to extract the data into a table.
Inspired by @hrbrmstr's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46755666/2799941).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

html <- read_html("~/Desktop/GenderStats.html")
xml_find_all(html, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", "$$$")
xml_find_all(html, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()

tbls <- html_table(html)
```

^The first key is to replace `<br>` tags with some distinct delimiter. Here I've chosen `'$$$'` but you can use anything unlikely to appear normally in the text you're scraping.

The reason for this is `html_table()` converts into nondescript whitespace - which becomes indistinguishable from whitespace within valid strings and then impossible to split on.

```
tbls[[1]] |> 
  rename(values_pct = `Values, n (%)`) |>  # just for ease of typing
  filter(values_pct != "") |> # drop "spacer" row entries

  # :Characteristics: values are now separated by $$$, split on that delimiter
  separate_wider_regex(Characteristics, 
                       patterns = c(var = ".*?", " \\$\\$\\$", category = ".*")) |> 
  group_by(var, category) |> 

  # now :values_pct: has entries like: $$$69 (68.3) $$$19 (18.8) $$$9 (8.9) $$$4 (4.0) 
  # however, some values for :var: have multiple rows already, like Sex
  # so we create a list column of :values_pct: , then expand into columns
  # with unnest_wide()

  # then remove leading $$$ values with str_replace()
  # finally expand each value into a column with separate()
  # then convert to long format with pivot_wider()

  summarise(values_pct = list(values_pct)) |> 
  unnest_wider(values_pct, names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(values_pct_1 = str_replace(values_pct_1, "^\\$\\$\\$", "")) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(values_pct_1, "$$$", names_sep = "__", 
                       too_few="align_start") |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(var, category)) |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> # drop empty values

  # now split :category: into one row per value, splitting on the delimiter
  separate_longer_delim(category, " $$$") |> 

  # the trick is to align each category with its associated value
  # do this by enumerating categories and values in the order they appear
  group_by(var, value = fct_inorder(value)) |> 
  mutate(value_id = cur_group_id()) |> 
  group_by(var, category = fct_inorder(category)) |> 
  mutate(cat_id = cur_group_id()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 

  # now reduce to just those entries where category ID and value ID match
  filter(cat_id == value_id) |> 
  select(var, category, value)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 27 × 3
   var                    category                    value       
   <chr>                  <fct>                       <fct>       
 1 Age                    <70 years of age            "63 (62.4) "
 2 Age                    ≥70 years of age            "38 (37.6)" 
 3 Brain metastases       Yes                         "16 (15.8) "
 4 Brain metastases       No                          "85 (84.2)" 
 5 CCI                    0–2                         "91 (90.1) "
 6 CCI                    ≥3                          "10 (9.9)"  
 7 Disease stage          IIIB                        "2 (2.3) "  
 8 Disease stage          IV                          "86 (97.7)" 
 9 ECOG PS                0                           "20 (19.8) "
10 ECOG PS                1                           "43 (42.6) "
11 ECOG PS                2                           "30 (29.7) "
12 ECOG PS                3                           "8 (7.9)"   
13 Frailty Scoring System Low                         "28 (27.7) "
14 Frailty Scoring System Intermediate                "41 (40.6) "
15 Frailty Scoring System High                        "32 (31.7)" 
16 Histology              Adenocarcinoma              "69 (68.3) "
17 Histology              Squamous                    "19 (18.8) "
18 Histology              NSCLC poorly differentiated "9 (8.9) "  
19 Histology              Others                      "4 (4.0)"   
20 NLR                    ≥4                          "58 (57.4) "
21 NLR                    <4                          "43 (42.6)" 
22 PD-L1 TPS%             <90%                        "74 (73.3) "
23 PD-L1 TPS%             ≥90%                        "27 (26.7)" 
24 Sex                    Male                        "75 (74.3)" 
25 Sex                    Female                      "26 (25.7)" 
26 Smoking history        No                          "93 (92.1) "
27 Smoking history        Yes                         "8 (7.9)"
```

Note: This still feels like a brittle solution and will almost certainly not generalize well.  Also verging on more suitable for [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) than SO, as it's less about coding (IMO) and more about thinking creatively through a data organization problem. Keeping it here in the spirit that it may be helpful to others learning to code in R/tidyverse.

**Original**
Here's a solution that pulls out each value in `List` and gives it its own row in the data frame that comes out of `tbls`. Then just drop the row with an empty `Value`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tbls[[1]] |> 
  rownames_to_column() |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(List = str_split_1(List, " ")[[as.numeric(rowname)]]) |> 
  filter(`Values, n (%)` != "") |> 
  select(-rowname)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Rowwise: 
  List   `Values, n (%)`
  <chr>  <chr>          
1 Male   75 (74.3)      
2 Female 26 (25.7)
```

Comment: Thanks you, this worked for above table. However it does not work when I try to scrap table from this URL as there are no spaces: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9953107/table/biology-12-00191-t001/?report=objectonly

Comment: Can you update your post with example data that reflects the actual data you want to scrape? As I noted in my comment, the html in your example data doesn't have a reliable structure and so solutions may not generalize well. The more your example covers the actual use case, the better others can help you.